# How to float a div under absolutely-positioned div (jsfiddle inside)

Tags: css, html

```
/* structure */

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#break {
    clear:both;
    }

/* header */

header {
    padding:15px;
    background:silver;
    }
#avatar {
    float:right;
    }
#brand {
    float:left;
    }

/* nav */

nav {
    clear:both;
    }
#menu1 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#menu1 ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    }
#menu2 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin:1px 0 0 0;
    }
#menu2 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#menu2 ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    }

/* main */

#commentswrapper {
    clear:both;
    }
#comments {
    clear:both;
    background:grey;
    }
#feature {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:600px;
    background:lime;
    }
#images {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 300px 0 600px;
    background:cyan;
    }
#recommend {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    width:300px;
    background:red;
    }
#main {
    position:relative;
    }
#mainwrapper {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    }
#title {
    clear:both;
    background:brown;
    }


@media screen and (max-width:1280px){

/* structure */

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#break {
    clear:both;
    }

/* header */

header {
    padding:15px;
    background:silver;
    }
#avatar {
    float:right;
    }
#brand {
    float:left;
    }

/* nav */

nav {
    clear:both;
    }
#menu1 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#menu1 ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    }
#menu2 {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    margin:1px 0 0 0;
    }
#menu2 ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#menu2 ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    width:150px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    }

/* main */

#comments {
    clear:both;
    background:grey;
    }
#feature {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:600px;
    background:lime;
    }
#images {
    margin:0 0 0 600px;
    }
#recommend {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    }
#main {
    position:relative;
    }
#mainwrapper {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    }
#title {
    clear:both;
    background:brown;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="brand">logo</div>
        <div id="avatar">avatar</div>
        <div id="break"></div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="menu1">
            <ul>
                <a href=""><li>nav1</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>nav2</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>nav3</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>nav4</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2">
            <ul>
                <a href=""><li>nav1</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>nav2</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>nav3</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>nav4</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="title">
        title
    </div>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
        <div id="main">
            <div id="feature">
                111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111
            </div>
            <div id="images">
                222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222 222
            </div>
            <div id="recommend">
                333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333 333
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="commentswrapper">
        <div id="comments">
            comments
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B95BX/

The #comments div, under the 3 main divs (#feature, #images, #recommend), floats perfectly when the browser is contracted to  less than 1280px. However, expanded, the #comments div only floats under the #images div because the 2 other divs are positioned absolutely. I understand why it's doing this, I just don't know how to work around it. How can I float the #comments div when the browser is greater than 1280px while still retaining the characteristics of all 3 divs filling the screen when maxed out with the middle div (#images) stretchable?

Comment: Can I get a side of CSS with that?

Comment: CSS added. If you follow this link (http://jsfiddle.net/B95BX/) you can see it all with live output so you know exactly what I'm talking about. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't float anything under an absolutely positioned div.

Absolutely positioned elements are taken out of document flow, which means they no longer affect the flow of other elements on the page.

If you know for certain the height of the positioned elements, you can place the comments element below it by either relative positioning or mucking about with it's margin-top style.

Otherwise, you'll have to look to a javascript solution to calculate the height of the absolutely positioned element and use that to move the other element to the desired location.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Do you know the name of the JavaScript that I'd have to use?

Comment: Well, I'm partial to jQuery. You can try $('#element').height() to get the height of the absolutely positioned element, and then adjust the margin of the item below it. I'd first look at alternative ways to achieve the design you are after. If I want my element to affect how other elements are laid out on the page, I'm usually able to figure out a way to do without absolute positioning. Can I ask why you need to position your element like that?

Comment: When the browser is maxed out greater than 1280px I need the 3 divs to fill the screen with the outer 2 divs at fixed widths and the middle div stretchable to completely fill the middle. Do you have a better way of achieving this without using absolute positioning?

Comment: what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: I think I understand the layout you are after. You should look at faux columns, it lets you cheat a bit with your layout :) http://line25.com/articles/create-sidebars-of-equal-height-with-faux-columns

Comment: I looked at the faux columns but I hate the word faux as much as I hate absolute so I figured something else out you might be able to use in the future.